# Mysql insert to main table with auto increment and link data in other table to the inserted main

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if the title explains it well, But I am sure that my explanation will explain it better:

I have a table called `Tracks` and a tble called `Flocks`.
each **Track** has many **Flocks** in it.

So when I insert a new track, a new ID is created with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` function, and in the same query, I want to insert the track's flocks aswell, but in order to make these flocks belong to the track I just inserted, I have to set their `track_id` to the auto incremented value.

I can do this in 3 queries, insert the Track, fetch the incremented ID, and then insert all flocks with the ID.

But I want to do this in one query, is that possible?

Comment: use trigger to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two queries unless you go for triggers or stored procedures:

- Insert the track
- use `last_insert_id()` as foreign key value to insert into flocks

example:

```sql
insert into track (name) values ('Trackname'); 

insert info flocks (trackid) select last_insert_id();
```

I normally group such tasks together in a stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure createTrack ( p_trackname varchar(20) ) as
begin
   insert into track (name) values (p_trackname); 

    insert info flocks (trackid) select last_insert_id();
end;
```

And then call it this way:

```
call createTrack("Trackname");
```

Comment: select last_insert_id() is an MySQL function?

Comment: it is. and it returns the last inserted auto_increment value generated in your session